# Python, Задачка по бинарному поиску

Tags: python, бинарный-поиск

Нужно вычислить загаданное число в заданном диапазоне. Не могу додуматься до алгоритма.

```
n = int(input('Введите начальное значение:')) 
m = int(input('Введите конечное значение:'))

while (n != m - 2):
    i = input(str(round(m/2))+'?>')
    if (i == 'м'):
        m = round((m+n/2)/2)
        n = m * 2
        continue
    elif (i == 'б'):
        m = round((n + m * 2)/2)
        n = round(m / 2)
        continue
    else:
        print('Введите "б/м"')

print('Задуманное число: '+str(n + 1))
```

Как правильно и наиболее оптимально его реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Надо ещё добавить возможность ответить "да" на случай если число *угадается* раньше чем алгоритм доделится до конца.

```
n = int(input('Введите начальное значение: ')) 
m = int(input('Введите конечное значение: '))

i = None
while n != m and i != 'д':
    if n > m:
        print('Обманщик!')
        break
    v = (m - n) // 2 + n     # вычисляем середину диапазона
    i = input(f'{v} ? > ').lower()
    if i == 'м':
        m = v - 1            # если меньше - сдвигаем верхнюю границу 
    elif i == 'б':
        n = v + 1            # если больше - сдвигаем нижнюю границу 
    elif i != 'д':
        print('Введите "б/м/д"')
else:
    print('Задуманное число:', v if  i == 'д' else n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())


while True:
    guess = (a+b) // 2
    answer = input(f'{guess} ?:')
    if answer == 'р':
        print(f'Your number: {guess}') # мы угадали
        break
    elif a==b:
        print('Stop deceiving me')  # мы не угадали, но других чисел нет.
        break
    elif answer == 'м':
        b = guess # загаданное число меньше - сдвигаем верх диапазона
    elif answer == 'б':
        a = guess # загаданное число больше - сдвигаем низ диапазона
    else:
        print('Введите равно(р) / больше(б) / меньше(м)')
```